# Problem with VLC video player on my Raspberry Pi 4

Tags: vlc, h264

I have captured video from a Raspberry Pi camera  and saved to desktop as video.h264. VLC player opens with huge window. I cannot navigate the window to get to any settings.

It worked fine for a few playbacks but now has defaulted to the screen you see from screenshot:[image]

Answer (score 2):

Solved issue. I had to change the Pi's display options in raspi-config to 1024x768.

Answer (score 0):

If vlc opens in the right-hand display it will crash.  It must be opened in the left-hand display only.  I have found no way around this.  Even if you open it in the left screen and move it to the right screen it will attempt to resize the window far too much and you can't do anything with it.